# Can I have other TWA app payment gateway?

Tags: google-play, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

Is it possible to have payment gateway in TWA app the same like on normal website? I heard that only Google Play payment gateway can be used in apps in the play store.

I want to keep my payment gateway as I have on the main page, ie Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are selling in your application. An application selling physical(eg: a shoe store) is not required to use Play Billing but an application selling Digital Goods (eg: subscriptions, unlocking features in the app, streaming content) is.

The best thing is checking out the Play Policy Center for details and see where your case falls: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9858738